# How do you declare an array and assign values to it inside a class?

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I have a class named "Toets" in a C# program named "Speletjie" and I want to declare an array of the class "Toets" and assign values to it inside the class.

My code for the class is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Speletjie
{
    internal class Toets
    {
        public string Vraag { get; set; }
        public string Keuse1 { get; set; }
        public string Keuse2 { get; set; }
        public string Keuse3 { get; set; }
        public string Keuse4 { get; set; }
        public string Antwoord { get; set; }

        public Toets(string v, string k1, string k2, string k3, string k4)
        {
            Vraag = v;
            Keuse1 = k1;
            Keuse2 = k2;
            Keuse3 = k3;
            Keuse4 = k4;
            Antwoord = "";
        }
    }
}
```

I have declared my array and assigned values to it in the main class like this:

```
Toets[] vrae = new Toets[20];

vrae[0] = new Toets("Hoeveel kontinente is daar in die wêreld?", "9", "7", "5", "4");
vrae[0].Antwoord = vrae[0].Keuse2;
vrae[1] = new Toets("Watter kontinent is 'n kontinent sowel as 'n land?", "Australië", 
"Europa", "Asië", "Afrika");
vrae[1].Antwoord = vrae[1].Keuse1;
vrae[2] = new Toets("Wat is Japan se hoofstad?", "Glasgow", "Beijing", "New Delhi", 
"Tokio");
vrae[2].Antwoord = vrae[2].Keuse4;
vrae[3] = new Toets("Watter stad in Suid-Afrika is die rosestad?", "Pretoria", 
"Kaapstad", "Bloemfontein", "Port Elizabeth");
vrae[3].Antwoord = vrae[3].Keuse3;
vrae[4] = new Toets("Hoeveel provinsies is daar in Suid-Afrika?", "9", "4", "2", "10");
vrae[4].Antwoord = vrae[4].Keuse1;
vrae[5] = new Toets("Die land grens nie aan Suid-Afrika nie.", "Zimbabwe", "Zambië", 
"Botswana", "Namibië");
vrae[5].Antwoord = vrae[5].Keuse2;
vrae[6] = new Toets("Watter buurland van Suid-Afrika word geheel en al deur Suid-Afrika 
omring?", "Swaziland", "Mosambiek", "Lesotho", "Botswana");
vrae[6].Antwoord = vrae[6].Keuse3;
vrae[7] = new Toets("In watter land is Shanghai?", "Indië", "Japan", "Pakistan", 
"China");
vrae[7].Antwoord = vrae[7].Keuse4;
vrae[8] = new Toets("Watter rivier skei die ou Transvaal en die Vrystaat?", "die 
Sabiervier", "die Vaalrivier", "die Tugelarivier", "die Mooirivier");
vrae[8].Antwoord = vrae[8].Keuse2;
vrae[9] = new Toets("In watter provinsie is Wakkerstroom?", "Noordwes", "die Vrystaat", 
"Limpopo", "Mpumalanga");
vrae[9].Antwoord = vrae[9].Keuse4;
vrae[10] = new Toets("Watter dorp is nie in die Vrystaat nie?", "Schweizer-Reneke", 
"Wesselsbron", "Viljoenskroon", "Dewetsdorp");
vrae[10].Antwoord = vrae[10].Keuse1;
vrae[11] = new Toets("Die dorp is nie in Suid-Afrika nie.", "Pofadder", "Uitenhage", 
"Leonardville", "Oranjeville");
vrae[11].Antwoord = vrae[11].Keuse3;
vrae[12] = new Toets("Die bergreeks loop tussen die noorde van Pretoria en die 
Mootgebied.", "die Magaliesberge", "die Drakensberge", "die Bronberge", "Tafelberg");
vrae[12].Antwoord = vrae[12].Keuse1;
vrae[13] = new Toets("Watter provinsie in Suid-Afrika is die grootste?", "die Noord- 
Kaap", "die Oos-Kaap", "die Vrystaat", "Noordwes");
vrae[13].Antwoord = vrae[13].Keuse1;
vrae[14] = new Toets("Watter dorp is die naaste aan Majuba?", "Vrede", "Volksrust", 
"Amersfoort", "Newcastle");
vrae[14].Antwoord = vrae[14].Keuse2;
vrae[15] = new Toets("In watter kontinent is Argentinië?", "Europa", "Noord-Amerika", 
"Asië", "Suid-Amerika");
vrae[15].Antwoord = vrae[15].Keuse4;
vrae[16] = new Toets("Die stad in Suid-Afrika is die jakarandastad.", "Johannesburg", 
"Pretoria", "Bloemfontein", "Kaapstad");
vrae[16].Antwoord = vrae[16].Keuse2;
vrae[17] = new Toets("Wat is Gauteng se hoofstad?", "Pretoria", "Germiston", 
"Johannesburg", "Kempton Park");
vrae[17].Antwoord = vrae[17].Keuse3;
vrae[18] = new Toets("Waar is diamante ontdek?", "Kimberley", "Johannesburg", 
"Bloemfontein", "Sandton");
vrae[18].Antwoord = vrae[18].Keuse1;
vrae[19] = new Toets("Watter stad/dorp is nie in Australië nie?", "Sydney", "Perth", 
"Madrid", "Canberra");
vrae[19].Antwoord = vrae[19].Keuse3;
```

I actually want to declare the array inside the class and assign values to it inside the class. How can I do that?

Comment: You mean like a [`static` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)?

Comment: I didn't get *where* you want to put that code. Into *which* class?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain into "Toets".

Comment: I'd recommend to think about that again: why should a class maintain an array of instances of its type? Why should a `Toets` (whatever that is) have an array of all other `Toets`? You *may* have a `static` array, that doesn't belong to a specific instance of the class but to the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array initializer like this:

```cs
// Toets = Tests
Toets[] vrae = {
    new ("Hoeveel kontinente is daar in die wêreld?", "9", "7", "5", "4"),
    new ("Watter kontinent is 'n kontinent sowel as 'n land?", "Australië","Europa", "Asië", "Afrika"),
    new ("Wat is Japan se hoofstad?", "Glasgow", "Beijing", "New Delhi", "Tokio"),
    ...
};
vrae[0].Antwoord = vrae[0].Keuse2;
vrae[1].Antwoord = vrae[1].Keuse1;
vrae[2].Antwoord = vrae[2].Keuse4;
...
```

Also I would use a different model:

```cs
internal class Toets
{
    public string Vraag { get; } // Question
    public int Antwoord { get; } // Answer
    public string[] Keuse { get; } // Choice

    public Toets(string v, int antwoord, params string[] kreuse)
    {
        Vraag = v;
        Antwoord = antwoord;
        Keuse = kreuse;
    }
}
```

This makes it easier to define the answer by specifying its index instead of copying the text. Also the number choices is now variable.

You would initialized it like this:

```cs
Toets[] vrae = {
    new ("Hoeveel kontinente is daar in die wêreld?", 1, "9", "7", "5", "4"),
    new ("Watter kontinent is 'n kontinent sowel as 'n land?", 0, "Australië","Europa", "Asië", "Afrika"),
    new ("Wat is Japan se hoofstad?", 3, "Glasgow", "Beijing", "New Delhi", "Tokio"),
};
```

Note also That I used get-only properties. Because once they have been initialized in the constructor, they will never change and thus don't need a setter.

Note that an array initializer does not need to be in a method. I am not sure in which class you want to put it. I assume on the `Toets` class itself? Then I would make it a static property.

```cs
internal class Toets
{
    public string Vraag { get; }
    public int Antwoord { get; }
    public string[] Keuse { get; }

    public Toets(string v, int antwoord, params string[] kreuse)
    {
        Vraag = v;
        Antwoord = antwoord;
        Keuse = kreuse;
    }

    public static Toets[] Vrae { get; } = {
        new ("Hoeveel kontinente is daar in die wêreld?", 1, "9", "7", "5", "4"),
        new ("Watter kontinent is 'n kontinent sowel as 'n land?", 0, "Australië","Europa", "Asië", "Afrika"),
        new ("Wat is Japan se hoofstad?", 3, "Glasgow", "Beijing", "New Delhi", "Tokio"),
    };
}
```

Since the property is static, you can access it through the class name like this (assuming `i` is an `int` used as index):

```cs
var vraag = Toets.Vrae[i];
```

If you are already using C# 12 you can use [primary constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/primary-constructors) and [collection expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/collection-expressions) (`[ ]` instead of `{ }`. The main difference is that an array initializer works only together with an array declaration, while as the collection expression can be used anywhere and not only for arrays.

```cs
internal class Toets(string v, int antwoord, params string[] kreuse)
{
    public string Vraag { get; } = v;
    public int Antwoord { get; } = antwoord;
    public string[] Keuse { get; } = kreuse;

    public static Toets[] Vrae { get; } = [
        new ("Hoeveel kontinente is daar in die wêreld?", 1, "9", "7", "5", "4"),
        new ("Watter kontinent is 'n kontinent sowel as 'n land?", 0, "Australië","Europa", "Asië", "Afrika"),
        new ("Wat is Japan se hoofstad?", 3, "Glasgow", "Beijing", "New Delhi", "Tokio"),
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the naming / structure might need a tweak. Assuming Google Translate has helped me out correctly, if you're trying to create some sort of home work test (Toets) then that class you've currently got might be better renamed as a 'Question'.

A 'Question' object (Vraag?) will want the text, the options and the answer associated with it. You'd probably then want another class called 'Toets' that instantiates a list of 'Question' objects. This can be done via the constructor, a creator method or many other means. So it would really depend on how you want to create the list of questions etc.